# Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules

Tags: makefile

When building an open source project I met error of:

```
make  subdir=manual -C manual ..=../ subdir_lib
Makefile:235: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

Code from line 235 of the Makefile as follows:

```
235: $(objpfx)stubs ../po/manual.pot $(objpfx)stamp%:
236:    $(make-target-directory)
237:    touch $@
```

Comment: have you looked at make -d output? hard to tell without complete example, so it's all theory here..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That error message is printed by GNU make when you have something that looks like a pattern rule output (containing a `%`) as well as something that looks like a normal output (no `%`) on the left-hand side of a `:` in a rule declaration.  For example:

```
%.pat normal:
        @echo $@
```

So on line 235 of your Makefile, you have managed to put together something that "looks like" that construct.  To avoid the error, fix that declaration, most likely by splitting it into two:

```
%.pat:
        @echo $@

normal:
        @echo $@
```

Without seeing the complete makefile that produced this error there's not much more advice we can give you.

Answer (score 18):

I am here to remind the successor, **check your path, is there any space in it**? 
We wasted all afternoon on this!

Comment: that was my case too, thnx

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the error was due to idiotically putting an extraneous : at the end of the dependency line:

```
%.o: %.cpp:
     g++ -c -o %@ $<
```

Answer (score 5):

Just had this myself and it was due to a hidden space after a "/" in a variable definition i.e.

```
#accidental/invisible space left after the final "/" i.e...
DESTDIR=path/to/the/destination/directory/ 
#                            ...just here ^

#rule to make copies of text files...
$(DESTDIR)%.txt:$(SRCDIR)%.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem described in this question has been reported here
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11873

The fix was indeed to split the rule, as suggested by Eric.

Answer (score 1):

Completing [Eric Melski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77345) answer, you can do this to avoid duplicating code everywhere:

```
define DEFAULTTARGET :=
    @echo $@
endef

%.pat:
    ${DEFAULTTARGET}

normal:
    ${DEFAULTTARGET}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your path, check where you have saved your projects, there shouldn't be a space in the name of the directory. Save it along with system generated projects directory files if u have imported it from another source

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have "space" character after path.

for example:
(this is a ' ' character at the end)

```
PATH_OUT = ../lib
```

then you use

```
$(PATH_OUT)/1.cc
```

and you will get this error

Comment: This seems to duplicate [an earlier answer from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979334/874188)