# Makefile: make clean - why getting mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax warning?

Tags: makefile

Following line `$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean`

Produces warning: `Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax`

What is wrong with it? Here is full listening:

```
obj-m := chardev.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    gcc -o ioctl ioctl.c

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: The error message is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules#answer-13945900).  My guess would be that it's from a Makefile read from `$(KDIR)`.  Did you try `make -d`?

Comment: Is this make 4.1 and an older kernel?

Comment: @EtanReisner this is make 4.0 and 3.16 kernel

Comment: @e0k `$(KDIR)` is just var, isn't it? Strange, but i can't find such error with `make -d`, only when performing usual `make`.

Comment: There is another Makefile being run in `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`.  I thought maybe that one had a mixed implicit & explicit rule  recipe.

Comment: Is that message a warning or an error? In make 4.0 it should be a fatal error. In make 4.1 it should be a warning. I thought the kernel was being changed to fix this... but maybe not. See http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=33034 for the GNU make "bug" about this.

Comment: I can't tell from your comment what's happening.  Can you cut and paste the make command line you entered and the exact output you're getting?  Do you see any commands invoked or do you just see that error?  If you see just that error then this means most likely you have not properly indented the recipe line (line 10) with a TAB character.  Every recipe line must be indented with a TAB.  I'm not sure why you're getting that error, unless you have a very strange working directory path or kernel uname -r when you run this.