# deprecated syntax error when calling external Makefile from another

Tags: makefile, compilation

When compiling a code, my Makefile checks object files in an external directory exist and if not calls a Makefile in another directory.

This rule in a `Makefile`

```
$(OBJECTSCOMMON)/%.o: ../common/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C ../common
```

is generating the error:

```
*** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
```

Is it a bad syntax?

Comment: `OBJECTSCOMMON` probably contains a space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules)

Comment: Citing the answer to the question you referenced: *That error message is printed by GNU make when you have something that looks like a pattern rule output (containing a %) as well as something that looks like a normal output (no %) on the left-hand side of a : in a rule declaration*. On the left side I have only `%` tarfet

Comment: As @user657267 says, the problem is likely in your `OBJECTSCOMMON` value.  What is that variable's value?  If you add `$(info '$(OBJECTSCOMMON)')` right before that rule what does it print?

Comment: There is an error in my question: it should have been `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o`. However this rule `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
 +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)` is working while this is not `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
 +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)`

Comment: Post a [mcve], anything else is just time wasting.