# what is making makefile error in the below code?

Tags: makefile

Iam getting error at 98th line and i dont understand why this error is happening.

```
makefile:98: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

and below is the code line at 98th line

```
$(SRC_C_OBJS): | $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Below is the code where above variables are used:

```
    OBJ_DIR = .\build

   _C_SRCS = $(PROGRAM)_i.c \
            test_$(PROGRAM).c

  _ASM_SRCS = $(PROGRAM).S

  _REF_C_SRCS = $(PROGRAM)_c.c \
              test_$(PROGRAM).c


REF_OBJS = $(_REF_C_SRCS:%.c=$(REF_OBJ_DIR)\%.o)
SRC_C_OBJS   = $(_C_SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)\%.o)
SRC_ASM_OBJS = $(_ASM_SRCS:%.S=$(OBJ_DIR)\%.obj)
SRC_C_OBJS += $(OBJ_DIR)/subsys.o

$(EXEC): $(SRC_C_OBJS) $(SRC_ASM_OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(SRC_C_OBJS) $(SRC_ASM_OBJS) $(LLIBS)
```

Comment: How is this related to cmake? What are the values of `SRC_C_OBJS` and `OBJ_DIR`? Please post all the relevant information needed to replicate the error, ie. create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would like to have the same error on my computer - what should I do?

Comment: You can check the edited code

Comment: Can you add ex. `all: echo $(SRC_C_OBJS)` and see what is really in there? The error message is that you can't mix `%` with normal rules, ex. `normal %.implcit:` is invalid. Now the question is, what is the value of `_C_SRCS`  `OBJ_DIR` `_ASM_SRCS` and `_REF_C_SRCS` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules)

Comment: Now check where its causing issue i have provided the values of variables that you have asked @KamilCuk

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> REF_OBJS = $(_REF_C_SRCS:%.c=$(REF_OBJ_DIR)\%.o)
> SRC_C_OBJS   = $(_C_SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)\%.o)
> SRC_ASM_OBJS = $(_ASM_SRCS:%.S=$(OBJ_DIR)\%.obj)
> ```

The `\%` is escaping the `%`, so it is interpreted as a literal `%`, not as the substituted string. The `/` is the directory separator on unix platforms, not `\`. You want:

```
OBJ_DIR = ./build
REF_OBJS = $(_REF_C_SRCS:%.c=$(REF_OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
SRC_C_OBJS   = $(_C_SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
SRC_ASM_OBJS = $(_ASM_SRCS:%.S=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj)
```

Theoretically, if `\` would be the separator, you could do:

```
REF_OBJS = $(_REF_C_SRCS:%.c=$(REF_OBJ_DIR)\\%.o)
SRC_C_OBJS   = $(_C_SRCS:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o)
SRC_ASM_OBJS = $(_ASM_SRCS:%.S=$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.obj)\
```

Answer (score 1):

Make was developed on and works with UNIX and POSIX paths.  POSIX paths don't have drive specs (`C:` etc.) and they use forward slash (`/`) not backslash as directory separators.  Make was not designed for and doesn't so work well with native Windows paths (drive specs and backslashes).

In particular, make often treats the `:` in a drive spec as part of a rule definition (note how in a rule definition the `:` separates the target from the prerequisites).  It also follows the standard UNIX/POSIX convention that backslash is used for escaping special characters (at least in some places).

So.  First, when asking questions on StackOverflow be sure to include critical details such as (a) what operating system you're using and (b) what version of the tool (in this case make) you're using.

Second, the example you gave above is missing absolutely crucial details: you did not include the assignment to the `REF_OBJ_DIR` or `PROGRAM` variables.  Without this we cannot be sure exactly what the problem is.

In general when writing makefiles you should avoid using drive specs and you should use forward slashes not backslashes as directory separators.  Most Windows programs will accept forward slashes (only certain old `command.com` programs won't).  If you must use drive specs, you'll need to get a version of make which is compiled to understand Windows paths.

One other thing, just to head off another common problem: make does not work well with paths containing spaces... so avoid them.