# Makefile Error: mixed implicit and normal rules error at CentOS 7, but not with CentOS 6.9

Tags: makefile

I'm using virtual machine to compile, with CentOS 6.9, and it works great.

However, i've installed CentOS 7 at my original PC on WSL.

I've copied the build toolchain to my CentOS 7 from /opt, CentOS 6.9.

Then i used `make` command to build my image.

and it shows this error

```
Makefile:433: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

So I've looked at the Makefile and it shows like this.

```
    429 vendor_%:
    430         $(MAKEARCH) -C vendors $@
    431
    432 .PHONY: linux
    433 linux linux%_only:
    434         @if [ $(LINUXDIR) = linux-2.4.x -a ! -f $(LINUXDIR)/.depend ] ; then \
    435                 echo "ERROR: you need to do a 'make dep' first" ; \
    436                 exit 1 ; \
    437         fi
    438         $(MAKEARCH_KERNEL) -j$(HOST_NCPU) -C $(LINUXDIR) $(LINUXTARGET) || exit 1
    439         if [ -f $(LINUXDIR)/vmlinux ]; then \
    440                 ln -f $(LINUXDIR)/vmlinux $(LINUXDIR)/linux ; \
    441         fi
    442
```

I have no idea why this error message comes out only at my CentOS 7 on WSL.

So i've checked this
[Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules)

it says

> So on line 235 of your Makefile, you have managed to put together
> something that "looks like" that construct. To avoid the error, fix
> that declaration, most likely by splitting it into two:
>
> ```
> %.pat:
>        @echo $@
>
> normal:
>        @echo $@
> ```

So, maybe to fix my error is to split it in to two, but it looks quite different between with my codes and that URL's codes.

What should i do?

Comment: Presumably, you are getting an error because the more recent version of `make` on CentOS 7 is more picky than the older one on CentOS 6.  The proximal problem is here: `linux linux%_only:`.  Make does not want you to have one target with a `%` and one without in the same rule. Therefore, make a separate rule for each target, both with the same recipe.  This is *exactly* what the answer to other question you pointed out  recommends and demonstrates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules)

Comment: I mean, examples on the internet will almost never look exactly the same as your specific code.  You should extrapolate the change from the example and apply the equivalent change to your specific code.